# Issues with newest phantom verson not loading my website

Tags: phantom-wallet

Rjctdlabs.xyz is my community staking and game platform

We can access it now problem with Chrome, pc, Mac, solflare mobile etc, but phantom wallet just pushed an update on the 6th and 7th that just doesn't load anything on my platform...

We can use old versions of phantom and it works fine....

Any ideas or suggestions as to how my dev can fix this on our side? Lots of other platforms still load without issue

Comment: Please keep the questions related to Solana development only.

Comment: This is though fam...

Comment: Our platform is all Solana, and using phantom wallet there's issues, trying to get any insight

Comment: Ah okay, my bad. The question doesn't have enough details or specifics about the issue and hence sounded more like a user experience with Phantom wallet on a platform. Can you elaborate more on what do you mean by "doesn't load anything"? Does the wallet connect not work? Are you using Solana wallet adapter?